# Android widget view doesn't clear contents on refresh

Tags: java, android, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I'm building an Android widget and have a layout file which will be included `n` times in the parent layout depending on how much data is available.

E.g if there are 3 pieces of data available, I build up the widget as follows:

```
widget.xml
   status_layout.xml
   status_layout.xml
   status_layout.xml
```

To include the `status_layout.xml` views, I do the following from an update service for the widget:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
RemoteViews childView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.status_layout);
 childView.setTextViewText(R.id.platform, 
         "Test text goes here \n " + new Random().nextInt());
views.addView(R.id.layout, childView);
```

This works fine the first time it is called, but subsequent updates are painted *on top of* the existing view instead of replacing it. This makes the text unreadable.

**Extra code**

Attempt to clear existing view:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
views.removeAllViews(R.layout.widget); // doesn't work
views.removeAllViews(R.layout.status_layout); // doesn't work
```

Trigger refresh when button is clicked:

```
int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class));
Intent refreshIntent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
refreshIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
refreshIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, refreshIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refresh, pendingIntent);
```

I've tried messing around with it a fair bit but can't figure out why - any help would be greatly appreciated.